# Plotting pandas dataframe using groupby - TypeError: no numeric data to plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am having an issue plotting groupby data in python using matplotlib and would appreciate some help as I a new to python.

Aim: plot total incidents of flytipping in England (y-axis) by Time Period (x-axis) grouped by region.

First of all I subset my data:

```
  ##Total Per Region
    TotalPerRegion=data[(data['LA_Name']=='Total') & (data['Region'] != 'TotalEngland')]
```

Transform the data and group by region

```
TotalPerRegion=TotalPerRegion.groupby(['Year','Region'])['Total_Incidents'].sum().unstack(level='Region')

OutputRegion    East East Midlands  London North East North West South East  \
Year                                                                    
2012-13  56484         40059  231894      56748     105201      66710   
2013-14  63829         44747  327484      50467     113596      70029   
2014-15  68373         48946  367075      50837     108536      74484   
2015-16  69461         50694  320137      48067     117529      69315   
2016-17  75447         60969  349878      53005     128193      79911   
2017-18  72832         68470  284250      62037     111920      79307   
2018-19  67792         69237  324261      63646     112069      83752   

Region  South West Total England West Midlands Yorkshire and The Humber  
Year                                                                     
2012-13      45182        714637         46425                    57536  
2013-14      53433        857655         56880                    67391  
2014-15      56166        905604         56895                    66051  
2015-16      34390        941896         56466                    68883  
2016-17      44745       1011199         63806                    76545  
2017-18      56563        997553         59593                    86697  
2018-19      59334       1072431         65379                    97649
```

Then try to plot the data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
TotalPerRegion.plot()
```

This error then appears:

```
    raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

Can anyone provide any help to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What is `print(TotalPerRegion.dtypes)` ?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean, is this caused by a data type issue?

Comment: Only I want check actual dtyoes of dataframe

Comment: Year=object, Region=object, Total_Incidents=object

Comment: Thanks yes that solved one problem. I had another error say KeyError: Region, I resolved this using TotalPerRegion.columns.name = 'Region' which has now worked. Thanks for your help